# Emoticons for iOS iPhones

Tags: iphone, emoji, emoticons

I want to creat original emoticons for iphone iOS. 
What size and pixels do They need to be? I cannot find the answer to this question anywhere. Please help. Thanks =)

Comment: I always had this doubt, but it seems like the prebuilt emoji icons can only enabled and cannot be added to tr iOS

Answer (score 0):

Well, iOS doesnt come with any original emoteicons, most user download the 'hack' with emoji icons.

And i believe they are 16x16 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor/) to see what is size of emoticons used in IOS.